# Assigning an array to a higher dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, xtensor

This is very similiar / related to [Assigning in high-dimensional Xtensor arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45134968/assigning-in-high-dimensional-xtensor-arrays) .

I have more or less the same problem and wonder if there is anything better that one can do? In the end the answer marked as correct still requires an element-wise assignment in the end and does not really give an option to assign a whole array at once to a given axis.

As an example, in numpy-python I could do something along the lines of

```
x = np.zeros((2,2))
x[0] = np.ones(2)
print(x)
```

which upon running would return

```
 [[ 1.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.]]
```

Now in xtensor, I would like to do something similiar, i.e., assign a whole array along a specific axis. What I tried was

```
xt::xarray<double> x = xt::zeros<double>({2,2});
x(0) = xt::ones<double>({2});
```

but this does not work - essentially that is the same question as OP. Now the suggested solution is to do

```
xt::xarray<double> x = xt::zeros<double>({2,2});
for(int =0; i < 2;i++){
x(0,i) = 1;
}
```

This gives the correct result - however, this still requires me to loop over the hole axis instead of assign an array to the whole thing directly. Compare this to

```
xt::xarray<double> x;
x = xt::zeros<double>({2})
```

which allows me to assign a whole array at once if I have a 1D array. Is there any equivalent of this for assigning an array along a given axis in higher dimensionsal structures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use views to achieve what you want:

```
xt::xarray<double> x = xt::zeros<double>({2,2});
xt::view(x, 0) = xt::ones<double>({2});
```

See [view's documentation](https://xtensor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/view.html) for more details

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I didn't understand that the view syntax worked that way, I assumed based on the name that it was solely for viewing purposes, not for accessing the given object as well. Thanks so much, you made my day!

Comment: No problem! I'm gonna improve the doc to make it clearer. Do not hesitate to come on our gitter channel (QuantStack/Lobby) should you have any further question.